# White-Black dot on Laptop Display

Tags: colors, laptop-display, dead-pixel

I have noticed a dot on my laptop screen. The behaviour of this dot is changing under different background colors. I just want to know if this is a DEAD PIXEL of anything else and is there any fix for this. Here is some explanation and images...

---

With RED and BLUE background the dot becomes barely white:

[image]

With YELLOW OR WHITE background its gone and with GREEN background the spot looks BLACK:

[image]

Here is the strange thing heppening i will try to explain,

The conditions i have explained above are only applicable if the whole display is of one color and there is no other program open with white background (eg. any browser or file explorer etc).However if I open some program somewhere on screen (not full-screen) then the spot becomes white,no matter the screen wallpaper is green or red.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not any expert about this kind of problem, but check for **[IsMyLcdOK](http://www.softwareok.com/?Download=IsMyLcdOK)** application which has some useful tests that maybe can revive a dead pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a dead pixel. There are some apps that can unlock it but you may learn how to live with it if you don't want to pay extra....

Comment: My laptop is just 2 months old and i have spent around $1400 on this. This is so annoying.

Comment: It's not a dead pixel... it's closer to a stuck pixel. Use the link that Elektro provided... there are all sorts of utilities online that will attempt to revive it. Be patient and run the utilities. It's weird that opening another window on another part of the screen affects the pixel... but I'm not an expert either. Good luck, I really hope something works.

Answer (score 0):

From the details you have given, I think it might be a stuck pixel, rather than a dead one.

Because if the pixel is changing colors when subjected to different images, it means that it isn't atleast dead.

I would suggest you ask your display's manufacturer, if they could help with that, there is no specific guarenteed way to fix it that I'm aware of.

As you say, if your laptop is just 2 months old, it would probably be in the warranty period, you might consider getting it replaced. Repairs worth 1400 bucks on a new device, loudly says something is fishy with your laptop.